# Problema al utilizar el Foreign key y references

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Hola que tal tengo un problema al utilizar el FOREIGN KEY y REFERENCES con MySQL Workbench segun el dubugger es un error de sintaxis

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pedidos(

id_pedido INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    fecha_pedido DATE,
    cantidad_pedido INT,
    id_cliente INT,
    id_producto INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_pedido)

    FOREIGN KEY(id_cliente)
    REFERENCES clientes(id_cliente)
    FOREIGN KEY(id_producto)
    REFERENCES productos(id_producto)

)ENGINE = INNODB;
```

conste que tambien he intentado escribirlo de la siguiente manera:

```
    FOREIGN KEY(id_cliente), REFERENCES clientes(id_cliente),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_producto), REFERENCES productos(id_producto),
```

Copy Response:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY(id_cliente)     REFERENCES clientes(id_cliente)     FOREIGN KEY(id_p' at line 10

muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: estas creando la tabla cleintes y la tabla productos antes que esta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El formato correcto sería:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pedidos(
    id_pedido INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    fecha_pedido DATE,
    cantidad_pedido INT,
    id_cliente INT,
    id_producto INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_pedido),    
    FOREIGN KEY(id_cliente) REFERENCES clientes(id_cliente),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_producto) REFERENCES productos(id_producto)
)ENGINE = INNODB;
```

> Todas las sentencias llevan coma al final excepto la última.
>
> `FOREIGN KEY` y `REFERENCES` forman parte de la misma sentencia.

Si no creas previamente las tablas referenciadas el error será:

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `db_name`.`pedidos` (errno: 150
>   "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Toda la información en la ayuda oficial:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html